# Deploying asp.net core 3.1 websites with windows server core 2019 on azure

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, azure-web-app-service

Can someone help how I can deploy as anp.net web api core 3.1 on a windows server core 2019, on Azure.

I have tried following [the link](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/create-asp-net-vm-with-webdeploy.md)

I am having the error

```
******* CommandLine: ********** MSI (c) (E4:AC) [12:38:27:612]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire
install on the server. MSI (c) (E4:AC) [12:38:27:612]: Grabbed
execution mutex. MSI (c) (E4:AC) [12:38:27:644]: Failed to connect to
server. Error: 0x8007041D

MSI (c) (E4:AC) [12:38:27:644]: Note: 1: 2774 2: 0x8007041D 1: 2774 2:
0x8007041D MSI (c) (E4:AC) [12:38:27:644]: Failed to connect to
server. MSI (c) (E4:AC) [12:38:27:644]: MainEngineThread is returning
1601
=== Verbose logging stopped: 3/26/2020  12:38:27 ===
```

---

I have tried installing from powershell.  The following are the the error messages I am having.

Can someone help how I can deploy my app in IIS on the Windows core machine.

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature-Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument
>   -All Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature-Online : The term 'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature-Online' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:2
>   +  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature-Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocumen ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature-Online:String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundExcepti    on
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Thanks

Comment: That article uses Windows Server 2016 Datacenter so you should too. Windows Server is not supported by tons of MSI installers.

Comment: You can try my way to solve the issue, I will see the link you give and try to figure out.

Comment: Which version of server 2019 you created ?  I find a lot of resource in portal  and I have no idea to choose.

Comment: @Jason windows server core 2019

Comment: Which deploy mode you have used for asp.net core application?  Self-contained or Framework-depend? Have you added the azure VM to open the right port to allow the network?

Comment: Brando I have published using File System,  self-contained.  I am using asp dot net core 3.1.  I have to publish it on a windows core 2019 Virtual machine.  Yes, the the right ports are open.

Comment: Brando I have added error messages I am having in powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using the following command in powershell

```
import-module servermanager
```